# Как соединить два массива в С++

Tags: c++

Вот такой код. При выполнении ввожу: 5, (1,2,3,4,5), 5 (6,7,8,9,10), получаю -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 1 2 3 4 5. Почему появляются эти "-858993460"? Я так понимаю проблема в памяти, но как ее решить?

```
void main()
    {
        int array1[5], array2[5], merge[10], i, j, k, size1, size2, size;

        // elements qty for 1st array
cout << "Please enter the amount of elements in the array 1: " << endl;
        cin >> size1;
        // actual elements
        cout << "Please enter the array elements: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            scanf_s("%d", &array1[i]);
        }

        // elements qty for 2nd array
        cout << "Please enter the amount of elements in the array 2: " << endl;
        cin >> size2;
        // actual elements
        cout << "Please enter the array 2 elements: " << endl;
        for (k = 0; k < size2; k++) {
            scanf_s("%d", &array2[k]);
        }

        // making total elements amount
        size = size1 + size2;

        // merging arrays
        for (i = 0, j = size1; j < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
            merge[k] = array2[i];
        }

        // printing 3rd array result
        cout << "Now the third array looks like this: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << merge[i] << " ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Скажите, а где вы пытаетесь записать в `merge` массив `array1`? я что-то ничего подобного у вас не вижу... Скопируйте сначала элементы одного массива, потом другого - и все сделано. Понять, что вы хотите в `for (i = 0, j = size1; j < size && i < size2; i++, k++)` я что-то никак не могу...

Comment: Честно говоря, наверно ум за разум зашел уже. Как бы вы предложили это сделать? Спасибо

Comment: @Fswt, а откуда в заголовке цикла взялось k?

Comment: У вас обычная проблема - вы пытаетесь суммировать (или делать другую операцию) в неинициализированую переменную - и получаете "мусор" с "кучи" (которая heap), другие ошибки - не искал, первое - проинициализируйте нужную переменную нулём, если вам не понятно какую - инициализируйте все все переменные нулем, т.е. одна из первых строчек - присваиваете в i,j,k,sum нули, и в массивы тоже.

Comment: @Fswt в идеале, создать два цикла. В первом поочерёдно копировать элементы из `array1` в `merge`, во втором из `array2` в `merge`.

Comment: Что б массив был с нулями - делается так `int array1[5] = {0,},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого:

```
for (i = 0, j = size1; j < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
    merge[k] = array2[i];
}
```

Сделайте, например, так:

```
for (i = 0, i < size1, i++) {
    merge[i] = array1[i];
}
for (i = size1, i < size1+size2, i++) {
    merge[i] = array1[I-size1];
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо! // merging arrays
 for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
  merge[i] = array1[i];
 }
 for (i = size1; i < size1 + size2; i++) {
  merge[i] = array1[i-size1];
 }

Comment: то же самое можно выполнить и в одном цикле

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, можно, конечно. Но на мой взгляд вариант с двумя циклами проще и нагляднее, что в данном случае мне показалось важным :)

Answer (score 0):

Во первых ваши массивы обьявлены с конкретным размером `5` , а вы вводите количество обрабатывемых элементов. Какая гарантия, что вы не вводите число больше чем 5?

Во вторых после цикла:

```
for (k = 0; k < size2; k++) {
     scanf_s("%d", &array2[k]);
}
```

переменная  `k`  примет значение `size2`, но вы выполняете:

```
for (i = 0, j = size1; j < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
    merge[k] = array2[i];
}
```

Какая смысль в переменной  J, непонятно.  Фактически вы  присваиваиваете  элементу   merge[size2]  и последующим элементам  значения из второго массива, а остальные остаются неинициализированными

Answer (score 0):

**Fswt**, Вы указали в тегах C++, и даже используете объекты `std::cin`, `std::cout`, но почему Вы не хотите в полной мере использовать стандартную библиотеку для решения Ваших задач?

Я позволю себе сделать Вам несколько замечаний и предложу некоторые правки. Использовать их или нет - на Ваше усмотрение.

1. Вы используете массивы фиксированной длинны, какой тогда смысл запрашивать у пользователя их размер? Если использование массивов не является обязательным условием Вашего задания, используйте `std::vector`.
2. Вы одновременно используете `cin`, `cout`, операторы ввода-вывода и здесь же - `scanf_s`. Это функция точно не определена в стандарте C++, и ее наличие в библиотеке скорее всего опционально.

Предположим, что Вы согласились использовать вектор. Тогда можно реализовать ф-ию, которая будет читать данные из стандартного ввода и "складывать" их в массив:

```
auto processInput(std::vector<int>& array, std::istream& is) -> void
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(array));
}
```

*`std::copy` - это обобщенный алгоритм для копирования элементов из одного диапазона в другой, `std::back_inserter` - функция для создания адаптера итератора вставки, которая получает на вход контейнер и генерирует выходной итератор.*

Однако, если Вы попытаетесь использовать данную функцию в таком виде, как она реализована на данный момент, у Вас ничего не получится - нажатие клавиши Enter не прервет процесс чтения потока и, соответственно, он продолжится до тех пор, пока не будет сгенерирован сигнал (при условии, что Вы вводите данные с консоли) или не произойдет ошибка при чтении потока.

Условимся, что процесс чтения данных с потока должен быть прекращен по нажатию клавиши Enter, тогда нам нужно внести некоторые изменения в реализацию функции `processInput`:

```
auto prepareInput(std::istream& is) -> std::istringstream
{
    std::string tmp;
    std::getline(is, tmp);
    return std::istringstream(tmp);
}
```

Это вспомогательная функция, назначение которой - сформировать строковый поток ввода, который в дальнейшем и будет использоваться для чтения данных:

```
auto processInput(std::vector<int>& array, std::istream& is) -> void
{
    auto ss = prepareInput(is);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(array));
}
```

Для объеденения `array_a` и `array_b` Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `std::merge`:

```
std::vector<int> res;
std::merge(array_a.cbegin(), array_a.cend(),
           array_b.cbegin(), array_b.cend(), std::back_inserter(res));
```

Исходный код завершенной программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

auto prepareInput(std::istream& is) -> std::istringstream;
auto processInput(std::vector<int>& array, std::istream& is) -> void;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array_a, array_b;

    processInput(array_a, std::cin);
    processInput(array_b, std::cin);

    std::vector<int> res;
    std::merge(array_a.cbegin(), array_a.cend(),
               array_b.cbegin(), array_b.cend(), std::back_inserter(res));
}

auto prepareInput(std::istream& is) -> std::istringstream
{
    std::string tmp;
    std::getline(is, tmp);
    return std::istringstream(tmp);
}

auto processInput(std::vector<int>& array, std::istream& is) -> void
{
    auto ss = prepareInput(is);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(array));
}
```

Comment: Слышком все усложняете. Кстати для  таких операций лучше использовать std::list<int>   с намерением  обьединения с помощью  std::list<int>::merge. Нельзя повсеместно использовать std::vector, потому что часто другие контейнеры или  адаптеры контейнеров  имеют свои  собственные преимущества

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо за замечание!

Comment: пожалуйста, но только это было не замечание, а мнение.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я Вас понял :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за проделанный труд по объяснению других возможных подходов. Приму во внимание!

Comment: @Fswt, не за что! Рад помочь :)